# After login to my wordpress site user need to go through some additional security steps ?

Tags: wordpress, security, authentication

In my wordpress site i wants to add an additional step in user login.

Means After user enter username and password successfully. He/she has to enter the security question answer which is enter by the user at the time of registration.

Till he/she has not enter the correct answer is not able to access rest of the page.

I can able to redirect the user after login to security question answer page but here he/she can access all other pages without going any security validation.

Please suggest how to restrict user to access all other the pages before validating the security question answer page.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you let them answer all 3 questions in one form? That way you could verify the security question first and check for the right password/log-in immediately afterwards.

You could start here and build in the security step yourself: http://natko.com/wordpress-ajax-login-without-a-plugin-the-right-way/

Answer (score 0):

WordPress by itself does not provide such functionality of multi-factor authentication. Just redirecting the user after login process to security questions page will not work as the user is already authenticated and cookies are set in the browser. So the user can browse any authenticated URL without answering the security questions.

What should be done is to delay the authentication process of the user until the validation of security questions so that the authentication cookies are not set in our browser.WordPress has several free plugins that provide this functionality.

miniOrange 2-factor authentication plugin in WordPress directory enables to implement this feature easily. The user will have the option to set the security questions in the settings page of the plugin. These questions are presented in a single form after the login process. Without validating these answers users will not be able to navigate to any post-login page even if the URL is correctly entered.
It is better to go for such trusted plugins rather than creating the functionality from the scratch. This plugin is free to use after registration.

Check this guide to add [security question](https://www.blogtriangle.com/add-security-questions-to-wordpress-login/) in a few simple steps.